# How to create symfony model class inside the controller?

Tags: symfony, model, data-modeling

=============== MyManualController.php ===============

```
$mCC = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); 
$qCC = "CONFLICT QUERY HERE...";
$xCC = $mCC->getConnection()->prepare($qCC); 
$xCC->execute(); 
$sCC =
$xCC->fetchAll();
```

=============== Current Output ===============

```
[{
     "emp_name": "Sample"
     "adjustment": "0",
     "by_days": "10",
     "mos": "323",
     "by_mos": "0",
     "yrs": "27",
     "by_yrs": "0" 
}]
```

=============== Expected Output ===============

```
[{
    "emp_name": "Sample"
    "adjustment": 0,
    "by_days": 10,
    "mos": 323,
    "by_mos": 0,
    "yrs": 27,
    "by_yrs": 0 
}]
```

Comment: Not sure what that has to do with controllers or modeling but I am assuming the issue is that you are getting strings for your integer values?  This sort of thing happens when you use the default `\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` value of true.  Setting it to false will give you the expected integers.  How you are configuring your connection is a bit of a mystery.  Symfony sets it up correctly.  But you seem to be using your own configuration.

Comment: Thank you so much! At first sight, looks my "00001" value will convert to 1 but after I tried this, it follows to my database field type. It saved a lot of time to create api conflict read query.

Answer (score 1):

follow link https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html

you can create entity, or, follow doc for create manually class with example

Comment: Ok, thank you! I'll try. Means required to create entity. No direct modelling to the controller.

Comment: Exactly, this is the Model View Controller pattern (MVC). Your model should be designed outside controller :-)